# F#: generated IL code for seq{} vs other computational workflows

Tags: f#, computation-expression

When I compare `IL` code that F# generates for `seq{}` expressions vs that for user-defined computational workflows, it's quite obvious that `seq{}` is implemented very differently: it generates a state machine similar to the once C# uses for its' iterator methods.  User-defined workflows, on the other hand, use the corresponding builder object as you'd expect.

So I am wondering - why the difference?

Is this for historical reasons, e.g. "seq was there before workflows"?
Or, is there significant performance to be gained?
Some other reason?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an optimization performed by the F# compiler. As far as I know, it has actually been implemented later - F# compiler first had list comprehensions, then a general-purpose version of computation expressions (also used for `seq { ... }`) but that was less efficient, so the optimization was added in some later version.

The main reason is that this removes many allocations and indirections. Let's say you have something like:

```
seq { for i in input do
        yield i
        yield i * 10 }
```

When using computation expressions, this gets translated to something like:

```
seq.Delay(fun () -> seq.For(input, fun i -> 
  seq.Combine(seq.Yield(i), seq.Delay(fun () -> seq.Yield(i * 10)))))
```

There is a couple of function allocations and the `For` loop always needs to invoke the lambda function. The optimization turns this into a state machine (similar to the C# state machine), so the `MoveNext()` operation on the generated enumerator just mutates some state of the class and then returns...

You can easily compare the performance by defining a custom computation builder for sequences:

```
type MSeqBuilder() = 
  member x.For(en, f) = Seq.collect f en
  member x.Yield(v) = Seq.singleton v
  member x.Delay(f) = Seq.delay f
  member x.Combine(a, b) = Seq.concat [a; b]
let mseq = MSeqBuilder()
let input = [| 1 .. 100 |]
```

Now we can test this (using `#time` in F# interactive):

```
for i in 0 .. 10000 do 
  mseq { for x in input do
           yield x
           yield x * 10 }
  |> Seq.length |> ignore
```

On my computer, this takes 2.644sec when using the custom `mseq` builder but only 0.065sec when using the built-in optimized `seq` expression. So the optimization makes sequence expressions significantly more efficient.

Comment: May be worth noting that you can `inline` your custom builder methods to get some optimization.

Comment: @TomasPetricek: Is there any way to rewrite MSeqBuilder so that it generates code that's closer to the optimized state machine version?

Comment: @user1411900 There is no way to completely change how the compilation works (i.e. use state machine instead of function composition). But if you were to do this for something common like `async { .. }` you could probably submit a pull request to the compiler :-)

Comment: @user1411900 if you are willing to put in a lot of work, you can quote the whole expression and write your own optimizer. E.g. `optimize <@ my { for x in ... do ... } @>`

Comment: @t0yv0: `inline` doesn't provide any benefit in this case (not on principle, but by measurement). The performance penalty for `mseq` vs. `seq` is reduced by using the 64bit runtime by around 1/3^rd.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, computations expressions ("workflows") were a generalization of sequence expressions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/09/22/some-details-on-f-computation-expressions-aka-monadic-or-workflow-syntax.aspx.

But, the answer is certainly that there is significant performance to be gained. I can't turn up any solid links (though there is a mention of "optimizations related to 'when' filters in sequence expressions" in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/11/30/full-release-notes-for-f-1-9-3-7.aspx), but I do recall that this was an optimization that made its way in at some point in time. I'd like to say that the benefit is self-evident: sequence expressions are a "core" language feature and deserving of any optimizations that can be made.

Similarly, you'll see that certain tail-recursive functions will be optimized in to loops, rather than tail calls.